# Efficient ways to get rid of status "hot" and "damp"

Tags: dayz-standalone

Sometimes I just can't get rid of my "hot" status - and, when I keep running I also become "overheated". Taking off clothes seems to help - but very very slowly, and I still keep a dark-yellow "hot" status after 15 minutes of being naked and not moving.

With getting "wet" and "damp" it seems to be similar. Making a fire sometimes won't help. In that case you are getting "hot" and are still "damp" at the same time.

Wet or damp clothes / equipment don't seem to dry ever.

I have experienced all of the above also with light-green "energized", "hydrated" and "healthy" statuses.

Am I doing something wrong or have I misunderstood something? 
Are the problems described above all known bugs in DayZ Standalone?

Comment: I would say these are not bugs but rather extra features of dayz. The game prizes itself for being a very realistic game. If you are completely soaked and you create a campfire and place yourself next to it you cant expect to be bone dry within 15 minutes, the same applies for overheating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [DayZ Wiki](http://dayz.gamepedia.com/Temperature):

> **Your body temperature will decrease when:**
>   Remove clothing items.
>   Expose yourself to rain.
>   Take a dip in the sea, a lake or a pond - this makes your clothing items 'wet' or 'soaked' (fast)
>   You are outdoors at night (slow)
>   You are outdoors in a windy environment (slow)

The "fast" and "slow" indications refer to at what rate your status changes.

The wiki page also has useful information about getting warm:

> **You increase your body temperature by:**
>   Sit beside a Fireplace (very fast)
>   Wear extra clothing items and or Make sure your clothing items are dry.
>   Expose yourself to sunshine or Remaining inside buildings. (slow - moderate based on time of day\night)
>   Descend to lower altitudes
>   Moving (very slow, faster movement speed will neutralize loss)

Regarding the issue with clothes not drying from sitting beside a fireplace; I actually experienced this recently and may have a solution. Most of my clothes were dry, but my shoes and face mask stayed *Damp* no matter how long I sat by the fireplace. So I took them off and placed them on the ground next to the fireplace, and voila! They became dry straight away.

I don't know if it's a bug (since the *Damp* status disappeared pretty much instantly) but it kind of makes sense that the clothing dries faster while drying "on it's own." Might also be that the status just has become "stuck" on the item and you need to drop and re-equip the item for the correct status to show.

**The easiest solution to getting rid of *Hot* status I can think of would be:** go for a swim or walk around in the rain for a while to get wet and *Hot* status will eventually disappear. Afterwards, remember to wring out your *Wet* clothes to make them "just" *Damp*. Then use a fireplace to dry up. Optionally take off clothes and put them on the ground by the fireplace to (maybe) have them dry up faster.

Comment: thank you very much for your detailed answer. I have experencied my shoes drying instantly as well as soon as i took them off - I think it's a bug - you don't even have to be near a fireplace for that.

Answer (score 1):

Hot: Take off your clothes or wear lighter clothes, avoid sprinting. You can also go prone in a small body of water, be careful not to drown.

Damp: Wring out your clothes and sit next to a fire, keep sprinting - make sure you are not in the rain or dip in to the water while drinking.